# Are "play games get cash" apps like Mistplay legitimate?

Tags: rebate, loyalty-programs

Lately, I see a whole bunch of apps which basically all have a theme of "play mobile games, and get free money by doing so". I think the most widely advertised is Mistplay.

**At first glance, this doesn't seem legit** - most of such games are free to play (with microtransactions/ads), so how would the Mistplay owner, or other companies with such apps, make any money to pay people out rewards, never mind produce profit for the company?

Are those apps legit? If so, how?

Comment: Remember, when you're on a free service, you probably are not the customer -- your attention is the product that someone is paying for.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't really a personal finance question, and because "these companies" covers a huge and growing range of ways to try to monetize attention. (I started trying to list some, got to 10, realized I could keep brainstorming possibilities, and dropped the answer.)

Comment: "HOW MUCH I MADE $0.50 - $1.63 Per Hour" https://moneydoneright.com/passive-income/cash-back-and-rewards/apps-and-sites/mistplay-review/

Comment: I don't know the details but I have a friend who plays games online and she gets a small payment for it.  No requirements.  Whether you site is legit, I dunno.  Some are.

Answer (score 1):

The golden rule of evaluating something that might be a scam, is simply: "Why would someone pay me to do [x], how much *should* they pay, and am I exposing myself to potential fraud?".

So for something like this, you can easily see that someone would make money off of you looking at ads. In theory, they could offer 'kickbacks' to you, the ad viewer, as incentive.

The question is whether the money earned off of your attention span would be able to fund some meaningful payment to you. start from first principles: how much money does an app maker earn from you viewing a single ad? Maybe 1 cent? In that case, If you would need to watch 1,000 ads to earn a $10 rebate, then the profit to the app maker would be $0.

Keep in mind this assumes you are not influenced by the ad [counter to the reason someone is paying for you to see it].

I think in most cases, to the extent the listed rebate-type program actually exists, then yes you could assume that some money is available, but probably the hourly rate for such activity would be closer to $1 an hour or less, rather than $10 an hour. Remember that downloading such an app could expose your information to 3rd parties, and if you are required to insert personal information, there exists a risk that it would be distributed for future scamming.

It's probably also difficult to determine the true earnings rate, as the app maker likely has control over various levers that might make payment seem imminent when it would still require you to jump through more hoops.

Comment: Mistplay (the only one I'm even remotely familiar with) does NOT have ads per se. Their "ad" is just a list of games that are affiliated with them.

Comment: @user2932 Do the games affiliated with the ap have ads? Because they are surely getting a cut of *that* revenue, or else the rebates are fake. Money comes from somewhere. Mostly just as a small slice of already small ad revenue.